# What translation unit holds implictly defined special member functions?

Tags: c++

I'm using `boost::scoped_ptr` and a forward declaration in a header file:

```
//Bar.h
class Foo;

class Bar;
{

private:
    boost::scoped_ptr<Foo> _foo;
};
```

I don't implement my own destructor since the smart pointer will do the job.

I include this header file in multiple translation units and not all of them include the `Foo` definition. When trying to compile I get an error that `scoped_ptr` is deleting a pointer to incomplete type `Foo`.

Everything is fixed easily if I declare an empty destructor in `Bar.h` and implement it in `Bar.cpp`.

However I got the same error if the destructor is implemented in a header file.

So the question is: in which translation units do implicitly defined methods go?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: thanks, I picked your formulation

Comment: I have edited the last sentence in the body for the same reason. Also removed the reference to *default constructor/destructor*. In C++ a default constructor is a constructor that takes no arguments, regardless of whether it is implicitly defined or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is not correctly formulated. What you want to know is

*What translation unit holds implictly defined special member functions?*

[That's a mouthful]. And the answer is in each and every translation unit that *uses* (odr-uses) them.

For your particular use case, and because the `scoped_ptr` destructor requires the type to be complete, you have no option but to declare the destructor of `Bar`, and define it even if empty in a translation unit that has a full definition of `Foo`.

Alternatively, you could use a different type of smart pointer that does not have that restriction.

Answer (score 4):

> So the question is: in which translation units do header implemented methods go?

In all of them. That is, each TU gets its own (inline) implementation.

You will get the error here because obviously the destructor needs to have the definition of `Foo`. This is regardless of *where* the destructor is defined. If you define it in its own TU, then  that TU still needs to know the definition of `Foo`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But how does the linker solve multiple definitions of the same function then ?

Comment: @Andrew: *implicitly defined special member functions* are `inline`. The linker resolves that as with any other `inline` function, by picking one of the definitions and discarding the rest (this is an implementation detail, other things could be done, but this is how every linker I know behaves)